# C# WPF How do I add a border to a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, border

I'm creating a style for buttons in App.xaml. How can I add a border to the style? And how can I then use the style in MainWindow.xaml?

I couldn't find how to do it. I don't want to put it in a separate style for the sake of border.

Comment: "How can I add a border to the style" - styles don't have borders

Comment: "*I couldn't find how to do it.*" - that sounds like you did not do any search at all. The internet is full of examples and tutorials.

Comment: Good. Thanks. Do you know how you can use the style from the App.xaml in MainWindow.xaml? I can't write directly to MainWindow. According to the task, it is necessary to go to the App

Comment: I searched and couldn't find it, that's why I'm writing here. About border, they mostly output it separately, and I'm trying to record it with everything else

Answer (score 0):

in App.xaml

```
        <Style x:Key="BorderedButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="HotPink"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
```

and in the view

```
        <Button Style="{StaticResource BorderedButton}"/>
```